# Automatically pauseing rsync if target is full

Tags: linux, files, rsync, file-transfer

I need to transfer 80gb's of unsorted text documents from one computer to another and all I have is a 32gb USB. Is there an option to make rsync automatically pause when the USB is full without losing its place?

Manually watching and pausing it is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that just like this.

You will have to be more creative and e.g. split manually.

Fill USB stick with first 32G:

```
tar czf - / | dd if=/dev/stdin of=/usbstick/bla bs=32k count=100k iflag=fullblock
```

Write the first 32G of the resulting tar to the destination

```
dd if=/usbstick/bla of=/tarfile bs=32k count=100k
```

Fill USB stick with next 32G:

```
tar czf - / | dd if=/dev/stdin of=/usbstick/bla bs=32k count=100k iflag=fullblock skip=100k
```

Write the 32G-64G to the destination:

```
dd if=/usbstick/bla of=/tarfile bs=32k count=100k seek=100k
```

Do this (increment skip and seek by 100k each time) until the tar file on the destination is complete.

Finally, extract the tar

```
tar -C /destination xzf /tarfile
```

Man, I'd just connect a crossover cable.

Comment: if=/dev/stdin is unnecessary as it is default

Comment: The whole thing is of course only valid with the assumption that nothing (no-thing) changes on the sources between the different runs. (Better mount read-only and/or use a live CD.)